# ggplot2: "un-integrate" different geom shapes in the legend

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
A=seq(10,12)
B=seq(1,3)
C=seq(20,22)
df=melt(data.frame(A,B,C))

ggplot(df,aes(variable,value))+
stat_summary(
    geom="errorbar",
    fun.data=mean_se,
    aes(color="Error bars",group=variable))+
scale_color_manual(
    values=c("red","blue"))+
geom_point(
    aes(color="Data points"))
```

If you look at the legend, the legend shows a "line+point" shape for both blue and red.

I would like it if the legend showed that blue matches to a "line" shape, and red matches to a "point" shape.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the legend aesthetics as follows

```
 ggplot(df,aes(variable,value))+
      stat_summary(
        geom="errorbar",
        fun.data=mean_se,
        aes(color="Error bars",group=variable))+
      scale_color_manual(
        values=c("red","blue"))+
      geom_point(
        aes(color="Data points")) +
      guides(fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(linetype = 0, shape=''))
             , color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(linetype=c(0,1)
                                                         , shape=c(16,NA))))
```

Producing:

[image]